# How to identify if the error/warning is created with swiftlint rules

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-server, swiftlint

I am working on CI/CD setup for my xcode project. For code analysis i am using **swiftlint**. It is working fine and i am able to see all the errors and warnings in my xcode along with the description. I have also written the run script such that swiftlint only shows the errors and warnings during code analysis and not during build/run.

My issue is, after i integrate the bot with my Xcode server i am not able to identify whether the errors/warnings are generated due to swiftlint rules or by xcode.

Is it possible to identify if the error is due to swiftlint and not generated by xcode itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. [The blue part below is NOT from swiftlint, and the rest below it IS.]

[image: XCode Image]

It says "Shell Script Invocation Warning"

At the end of the message it gives you the rule that has been triggered inside parentheses

```
(function_body_length)
```

I just look for the messages ending in parens.

Comment: To add some clarity to this totally correct answer, if you look at your project's build phases where you added Swiftlint, you have a compile phase ("Swift Compiler Warning") and your Swiftlint phase, which is a Shell Script. That's how the warnings are split up.

Comment: @Mozahler Thank you so much. That was simple. I hope we will get this kind of segregation in Xcode Server issues api also